# How can I select text between anchors and highlight them as such?

Tags: javascript

I have some HTML that looks roughly like this:

```html
<div>
    <p>Herp derpsum sherper herpy derpus jerpy berps cerp terpus.
        Derpy merpus <a name="a1start" type="start"></a>pee derpler berps! Perp
        sherper herp terp herpy derpler.</p>

        <p>Sherper merp herpler herp pee. Derpler terpus, mer re berp
            der perp se?<a name="a2start" type="start"></a> Ze ter derps tee! Herpsum derp
            sherper ler merp derperker <a name="a3start" type="start"></a>jerpy derpler
            herderder zerpus.</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Derp sherper perper tee. Derperker
        zerpus ner cerp terpus herpy sherpus sherp. Perp derp pee serp herp
        zerpus herpem herderder derpler berp! Merpus derpy <a name="a1end" type="end"></a>
        herpler sherp derps perper derperker derp dee der. Merpus der
        derps, <a name="a2end" type="end"></a>derpus herpderpsmer! Derp merp er sherpus dee perp herpy derpsum
        perper pee. Herpler derpsum me sherlamer ler derpler derpy. Cerp de
        perper derpy. Le herderder herpler re ter. Serp ze derperker re. Terp
        berps terpus ter, er perp derpsum. </p>
<a name="a3end" type="end"></a>
</div>
```

In other words, anchors used to mark starts and ends of highlighted areas. They are irrespective of their locations in `<div>` or other containers. The highlights are **overlapping**, thus `a1start` corresponds to `a1end`.

I'm trying to figure out a way to highlight them, going from start anchors to end anchors, and ignoring all the HTML in between. So, one highlight from `a1start` to `a1end`. Another, overlapping highlight from `a2start` to `a2end`, and so on.

Note again that these are **overlapping**, so I can't just use spans, because then how would a given `</span>` know that it's the end of, e.g., `a2` rather than a closer one at `a1`?

In other words, think of this structure:

```html
<highlightA>
Here is something highlighted in A.
<hightlightB>
Here is something highlighted in A and B. 
</hightlightA>
Here is something only highlighted in B. 
</hightlightB> 
Here is something not highlighted.
```

I would usually just transform these `<a>` tags to `<span>` and `</span>`, and then highlight them with CSS: `span { background-color: yellow }`. But that would produce overlapping tag sets, no? Which is illegal in the HTML/XML world?

So I need to use JavaScript to identify these markers, figure out which ones match, and highlight those spans of text, without trying to edit the HTML. In other words, I need to overlay some highlighting on top of the page, without messing with this markup.

I'm a JavaScript beginner, so go easy on me, please.

**Edit:** [Here's a Codepen I put together which illustrates this problm a little better](https://codepen.io/jonathanreeve/pen/bGaqmKE), and tries to implement the (non-working) solution below. It uses different highlight colors to show how the overlapping highlights aren't working.

Comment: `a` tags are like this: `<a href='url'>some text</a>`. Where the `some text` is already highlighted by default css.

Comment: That's if you're using an anchor for a hyperlink. But you can use anchors for other things, too. You don't need to make it a hyperlink.

Comment: Misunderstood the question. You can use `<mark>` tags instead.

Comment: Then the question becomes: how can I transform these `<a type="start"/>...<a type="end"/>` tags to `<mark>`, such that it doesn't break the browser's HTML parser, because they're overlapping tags that jump over `<div>s` and others.

Comment: The other issue is that the tags are **overlapping**. So `<mark n=1>` would need to correspond to `</mark n=1>`, even if there's another `</mark>` that appears in the meantime.

Comment: very confused with the question with what do you want to do? It is always a good idea to post your expected result. Do you want to heighlight text between <a type=start> and <a type=end>?

Comment: In your example, the entire text from the first `a[name][type="start"]` tag will be highlighted with yellow. So what's the point?

Comment: @James, yes, the idea is to highlight text between matching anchors. So a1start to a1end, a2start to a2end, and so on.

Comment: @Jonathan Just wrap the text that has to be highlighted inside `<mark></mark>`. Like: `<div><p>Not highlighted text. <mark>This is a highlighted text.</mark> This is not highlighted</p></div>` Mark tag is by default `background-color: yellow`

Comment: @ask4you, that won't work, because the highlight will stop the second it sees a `</p>` tag. Try it: https://codepen.io/jonathanreeve/pen/oNpZyqQ

Comment: @ask4you, Not to mention, there's no way of saying that a given `</mark>` needs to correspond to **an earlier highlight**. That is, they need to be able to overlap.

Comment: @Jonathan try this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5zn91aq/#&togetherjs=7kkKlB2DJe)

Comment: @ask4you, I don't think you understand that the main issue here is **overlapping highlights**. So, `<markA>` needs to be ended only by `</markA>` and not by a generic `</mark>`.  A highlight needs to continue until it is ended by **its own marker**, and not the end of some other highlight.

Comment: I've edited my question to be more specific. See the example with `<highlightA>` and `<highlightB>` above.

Comment: You'd have to write your own parser, which is lightyears beyond the scope of what can be asked/answered on StackOverflow. Be aware that writing parsers for sure belongs to most difficult algorithmic problems that exist.

Comment: @connexo, what do you think is the scope of what can be asked and answered on StackOverflow? Is it only easy questions with easy answers? Also, a parser isn't necessary here. And they aren't hard to make. I've made a number of them in Python and in Haskell.

Comment: Ever thought of using markdown instead? Much easier to handle for these types of assignments. It would be easier to understand the question if you stated what this should be used for, because I don't know if this is part of a solution that you thought up, and that might not be the right way to go.

Comment: I still don't get how you will decide on what color to use. If `a1start` overlaps `a2start`, both text will have yellow background, according to your description.

Comment: @RickardElimää, as for color, you could just use yellow at, e.g., opacity of 20%. That way if there are overlaps it just makes the highlight a little darker. I don't understand what you mean by markdown. It's still going to have to be transformed into HTML, anyway, so the problem's still there.

Comment: Yeah, but why is it formatted like that in the first place? Where does the code come from? If it's a user that marked the code, markdown doesn't have that kind of limit, and it will format itself to proper HTML code. I began writing an answer, but gave up after an hour (and because I have a fever). Guess this is a 3-4 hour assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Class Applier Module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Class-Applier-Module) of the [Rangy Library](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/) solves exactly this kind of problem.

[demo](http://lezuse.github.io/rangy/demos/classapplier.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in the fact that in order to solve your issue, your closing tag needs to match the opening tag. I have been looking around, and certainly, I don't think you can add attributes to the closing tag to make a pair with the opening one. So, why not make your own tag?

I present to you this very simple [code](https://codepen.io/mankinchi/pen/yLpPqYB)

The code is purely just HTML and CSS as you will see here.

```
<test1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <test2>Nam at quam euismod, </test2>commodo nibh vitae,</test1>
```

I think there might need some JS to work on other machines depending on this [guide](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/). However, I don't need to do that one for this to work (you can check the JS tab in the codepen). I think you would want to do this if you are planning to use some functions provided by the browser for the original tag (look for `extending original tag` in the guide).

I'm not so good with CSS and color blending too so I have skipped that part, but I think you can work on that issue on your own. In my code, the `test2` color will override the `test1` completely.

That's all. Feel free to comment if you need anything else explained :D

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question, which is that the tags are overlapping. In your example, tags are nested, but not overlapping.

Comment: @Jonathan ah I see the issue there. When I tried overlapping, the tag is being closed before it should be. Okay I will think a bit more about this

Answer (score -1):

This works in Firefox, and possibly other browsers (I haven't tested).

It's beautifully simple, requiring only a single css rule applied to a class added to your 'start' anchors.

In the working snippet I've added a `class` attribute named "open" to just the start anchors, and a corresponding style rule to css.

The reason why this doesn't break the document tree is explained as I understand it, below.

```css
a.open {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Herp derpsum sherper herpy derpus jerpy berps cerp terpus.
        Derpy merpus <a name="a1" type="start" class="open"/>pee derpler berps! Perp
        sherper herp terp herpy derpler.</p>

        <p>Sherper merp herpler herp pee. Derpler terpus, mer re berp
            der perp se?<a name="a2" type"end"/> Ze ter derps tee! Herpsum derp
            sherper ler merp derperker <a name="a3" type="start" class="open"/>jerpy derpler
            herderder zerpus.</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Derp sherper perper tee. Derperker
        zerpus ner cerp terpus herpy sherpus sherp. Perp derp pee serp herp
        zerpus herpem herderder derpler berp! Merpus derpy <a name="a4" type="end"/>
        herpler sherp derps perper derperker derp dee der. Merpus der
        derps, derpus herpderpsmer! Derp merp er sherpus dee perp herpy derpsum
        perper pee. Herpler derpsum me sherlamer ler derpler derpy. Cerp de
        perper derpy. Le herderder herpler re ter. Serp ze derperker re. Terp
        berps terpus ter, er perp derpsum. </p>
</div>
```

I discovered it by examining the document tree interpreted from your html in the browsers developer tools. It turns out (in Firefox at least) the browser adds discrete closing tags `</a>` to any self-closing versions (`.../>`) written in the html document. Moreover, as it doesn't know where the self-closing anchor is due to end, it adds an end tag before any other html elements that would 'break' it and, cruicially, applies a duplicate opening anchor of the same name to the next html element, immediately after it's opening tag and closing it again before any further tags that would break it. Thus, the browser is duplicating the last self-closing anchor to every part of the tree until a new anchor replaces it.

This allows you to add a class to just the anchors where you want a style to begin (it will end automatically when an anchor without that class is encountered - so only put them in anchors 1, 3, etc.)

In case this doesn't work for users of other browsers, here's a screen shot of the result in Firefox.

[image: screen shot showing output in Firefox]

If your browser doesn't make the same interpretation, I'd urge you to examine the document tree in browser tools to determine how the self-closing anchor is applied and got from there.

After the fundamental changes to the question, I reworked the principle described here with minor modifications to achieve overlapping styles across element boundaries, determined by the anchors as per the question. Screen shot of result:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. One way you can tell is that "Ze ter derps tee!..." isn't highlighted at all. But it's actually a part of the a1 highlight, which doesn't end until "Merpus derpy..." several lines later. Everything between `a1start` and `a1end` is one highlight; everything between `a2start` and `a2end` is another highlight, and so on.

Comment: I updated the HTML in my question so that it's valid HTML, but even with self-closing tags, like I had before, I think you'll run into the same issue, which is that the browser can't see (and shouldn't be expected to see) that the `a1 type="start"` corresponds with the `a1 type="end"`. Which is why I'm looking to do this with JavaScript.

Comment: I've given you the key to reworking your tags, you just need to properly explain what your end result is. If you can't manage that, edit your html to include (not in tags) what you want to achieve, like "Red start here" .... "yellow start here" ... "yellow end here" ... "red end here". If you do that, I'll show you (it's very easy with what I've given you).

Comment: Incidentally, nothing in your html ends anything at "Merpus derpy..." and, even if it did, it would have to be clear that ending applied to the first opening anchor. If a human can't parse the html, a computer can't either.

Comment: The end result is overlapping highlights. They should be yellow, probably at some alpha or opacity value of 20% or so, and get darker if there's an overlap. There's nothing you need to change in the HTML. And in fact, HTML won't work, since there's no way you can say that a given `</a>` tag corresponds to a particular `<a>` from several lines up, and *doesn't* correspond to an `<a>` tag which came later.

Comment: It's easy for a human to parse. Look at the `name` attributes. `a1start` matches with `a1end`, and `a2start` matches with `a2end`. Crucially, `a1end` does **not** end `a1start`, and `a2end` does **not** end `a1start`, and so on.

Comment: Also, are you looking at the question, in its most recent form? Try reloading the page, and you'll see "Merpus derpy...". But the point is that `a1start` must only be ended by `a1end`, and can't be ended by `a2end`. So the solution you have here won't work.

Comment: The html I used was copied directly from your question. I can easily modify the simple solution I gave you to match your changed html but am not going to until tomorrow when you've finished moving the goal posts (unless you've figured it out by then, which should take you 2 minutes).

Comment: I don't think you understand why your solution doesn't work. If it worked, "Ze ter derps tee!" would be highlighted, since the A1 highlight hasn't yet finished. Each highlight is different and can only be closed by the tag that started it, not some other tag. That's the problem. 

You can see from my edit messages that all I'm doing is making my question more explicit. I'm not "moving the goalposts," I'm helping people to understand this question, which is apparently really hard for people to understand.

Comment: My solution doesn't work to the current version of your changed markup, but would do with minor modification. The key to your solution is in how the browser applies overlapping anchors.

Comment: It doesn't, unfortunately. I put together a codepen to show you why, even though, in all fairness, the burden of proof should be on you—you should have to prove your solution works, rather than leave it to me to prove that it doesn't. See https://codepen.io/jonathanreeve/pen/bGaqmKE. You can see that the beginning of the next highlight ends the previous highlight, when the previous highlight should only be ended by its own corresponding end tag. The second highlight never gets triggered at all, and the third endr prematurely, as well.

Comment: You have a very strange idea of what stack overflow is for. You have the responibility to define your problem and ask your question clearly. Neither should you expect answers to do your work for you, their purpose is to help you understand where you are going wrong and give examples of approaches that might help you to advance. There is no burden of proof on any one who takes time to answer your question. I have a fully working example of the SIMPLE modification you need, based on  my observation of how the browser reads the tags. Will post screen shot, but you can work it out for yourself.

Comment: You have a very strange idea of what constitutes an answer, if you just post a screenshot, without the code that produced that screenshot. Anyone can produce a fake answer by just constructing a screenshot that appears to show a working solution. I've already demonstrated in the codepen that the approach in this answer doesn't work—neither on Firefox nor on Chrome. The reason it doesn't is that, even if the browser can automatically close self-closing `<a>` tags, it has no way of knowing where the end is supposed to be, because it can't match the start and end tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243354/discussion-between-dave-pritlove-and-jonathan).